# Searching for a String within a larger string

Tags: c++, string, find

I really need help with this last part of my program. I need to find a string within a larger string and if found return the start location of the substring. From the directions:

> Note that your string location starts from 0 and ends at length -1. If the string is not found, a value of -1 will be returned.

I've started and the following code compiles, I just want to know if this is actually correct. I don't want to get in too over my head but I need some feedback from experts. Am I doing this right? Or at least am I going in the right direction?

```
const int MyString::Find(const MyString& other)
{
    int start(0);
    int counter(0);
    int end = other.Size;
    int count(0);
    int end1 = Size;
    int nfound = -1;
    char* temp;

    if(other.String[0] != '\0' && other.String[0] != ' ')
    {
        if(other.String[count] == String[counter])
        {
            start = counter;

            for(int i = count; i < end-1;i++)
            {
                for(int j = counter; j < end1 -1; j++)
                {
                    temp[j] = String[j];
                }
            }
            if(other == temp)
            {
                return start;
            }
            else
                return nfound;
        }

        else{
            while(other.String[count] != String[counter])
            {
                counter++;
                if(other.String[count] == String[counter])
                {
                    start = counter;
                    for(int i = count; i < end-1;i++)
                    {
                        for(int j = counter; j < end1 -1; j++)
                        {
                            temp[j] = String[j];
                        }
                    }
                    if(other == temp)
                    {
                        return start;
                    }
                    else
                        return nfound;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return nfound;
    }
}
```

Comment: SO is not a place for people to review your code; you might want to try the Code Review SE site.

Comment: Not directly related to the Q: you've got a memory leak: you allocate with `new[]` (which you don't even need to) but you never `delete[]`.

Comment: @jrok thank you! I have edited the code on account of the leak you have pointed out.

Comment: Wait wait, you DO need `new` in this particular code snippet! What I meant was that you don't really need a dynamically allocatted char array to implement a find function. See Steve Jessop's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you don't want to do anything very sophisticated, consider that `needle` is a substring of `haystack` if and only if there is some index of `haystack` for which the substring starting at that index is equal to `needle`.

Also, you don't need to copy lots of substrings around. Starting from your chosen index, just compare character-by-character until either (a) you find a mismatch, in which case try another index, or (b) you run out of `haystack`, in which case no match is possible for this or any greater index, or else (c) you run out of `needle`, in which case you've found a match, so return the index you're working from.

If there's more than one match (for example searching for `"na"` in `"banana"`), then hopefully the directions tell you which one to return. This tells you what order to consider the indexes in `haystack`.

If you do want to do something very sophisticated, look up Boyer-Moore, Knuth-Morris-Pratt, and a number of other published string search algorithms with different trade-offs. It seems to take more than one person to invent a good one.

Comment: thank you! this has helped a lot, now I just have one question: What is the most efficient way to do this if it isn't using loops? Well, 2 questions: I always trip up off of returning the start location because there seems to be no way to retract and get the start location after comparing all characters

Comment: The most efficient way is not to do it at all -- not yourself. Use a library that's debugged and optimized for your convenience.

Comment: @user1363061: there are a number of ways to get the start location. One would be to store it in a variable while you compare the characters. Another would be to subtract the length of `needle` from whatever offset in `haystack` you end up in. The issue of what's most efficient is too complicated to admit a simple answer. Each algorithm has certain inputs (or categories of input) on which it does better or worse.

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda bad code from my point of view. 
\0 is used in char*-strings to indicate end of the string. There is no need no use it in class that incapsulates strings.
There are many algorithms to find substring in string, one of them is Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm. Other are listed in this article [String searching algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm)

Comment: "There is no need no use it in class that incapsulates strings" -- and yet, `std::string` does. Admittedly, that's really just  to support the `c_str()` function.

Comment: I mean, no need to use it explicitly. It makes code less readable. Somethind like `if(str.empty())` is much more readable than `if(str[0] == '\0')` and it will be easier to replace your ANSI-string with Unicode string, for example